# How to Set a MYSQL Variable Value to 1 when text is clicked in php?

Tags: php, mysql, private, message

First off I know very little about php and am still learning so please go easy on me with your answers. Basically I'm working on a project that functions like a social network site, users are able to send and receive private messages etc. I have got this all working great and the messages even go to the messages_deleted.php page when you set the variable value from '0' to '1' in the database.

Is there a way to let the user do this themselves, to delete their own messages by clicking a piece of text?

I'm working in php so would need a piece of php code which allows me to do this if anyone has any ideas?

Here is my current php script I'm using:

```
<?php


    $page_title = "Messages";
        include('includes/header.php'); 

        confirm_logged_in();

        include ('includes/mod_login/login_form.php');  
    ?>

<div class="modtitle">
  <div class="modtitle-text">Inbox</div>
</div>

<div class="modcontent">

<strong>Inbox</strong> | <a href="messages_sent.php">Sent Messages</a> | <a href="messages_deleted.php">Deleted</a>
<br /><br />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <td width="30%"><strong>Recieved</strong></td>
    <td width="20%"><strong>From</strong></td>
    <td width="28%"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
    <td width="0%"><strong>Read/Unread</strong></td>
      <td width="0%"><strong>Delete</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
        $inbox_set = get_inbox();
        while ($inbox = mysql_fetch_array($inbox_set)) {

?>

<?php
 if ($inbox['read'] == 0) { ?>
  <tr bgcolor="#6666B3">
<?php }
 if ($inbox['read'] == 1) { ?>
    <tr>

<?php }  ?>



    <td><?php 



    $datesent1 = $inbox['date_sent'];


    echo "$datesent1"; ?></td>


    <a href="profile.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}"><td><?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}\">{$inbox['display_name']}"; ?></td></a>

    <td><?php echo "<strong><a href=\"read_message.php?msg={$inbox[0]}\">{$inbox['subject']}</a></strong>"; ?></td>

    <td><?php   if ($inbox['read'] == 0)  {
                echo "Unread"; 
                }
                if ($inbox['read'] == 1)  {
                echo "Read";
                }
                ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                if ($inbox['delete'] == 0)  {
                echo "Delete";


                }
                 if ($inbox['delete'] == 1)  {
                echo "$deleted_set;";
                }   


                    ; ?></td>



                </td>

<?php
}


?>

</tr>
</table>

</div>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

---

What I really need is a way of making the 'delete' row clickable so that when a user clicks on it it sets the value to '1'. If it can be done that way it would be a lot easier for me I think.

Comment: If you know how to get messages into the database, it's not that much different. If you're limited to only using PHP (no JavaScript), then I'd wrap the message listing view in a form, place a checkbox in front of each message, add a delete button that acts like a submit, and the user basically posts this to the page and then you loop through each submitted message and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is quite simple. You can take a look at some basic jQuery and AJAX working on the page. Here's a link to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of the API.

Comment: ok thanks. thats already setup, so when the user deletes a message it gets submitted to the messages_delete.php page and you can go to deleted messages to see it in their. but the messages only get deleted if their value is set to 1 in the mysql database and i am looking for a code that will allow the user to set this value from 0 to 1 when they click the delete text. thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumptions

If you can include jQuery to your project, then you can use PHP + AJAX to work on this. Say, you have the PHP file which makes the message deleted as `messages_deleted.php`. And to delete a message, I assume that, you need to pass a parameter `id` to the script, which finally comes this way: `messages_deleted.php?id=5`.

Also assuming that the code in your **PHP file** is:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect();
    if (mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET `deleted` = 1 WHERE `id` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"])))
        die ("deleted");
    else
        die ("error");
?>
```

#### Code

You can use jQuery's [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to do the work for you.

And if the message is valid and deleted, your PHP Script should `die("deleted");`. Adjust accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table tr").click(function(){
        $.getScript("messages_deleted.php", function(data){
            if (data == "deleted")
                alert("Message Deleted");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i've attached the code because it will probably help. is that compatible with the code in your example? or can you let me know what needs to go where. thank you.

Comment: @MarkTanner If you don't use more than one `<table>`, please see the updated answer in few mins. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use Ajax, you should create a link that redirects user to a page for example `delete_message.php?mid=16` where mid is the message id users wants to delete,

then on server side first check that this message belongs to the user that wants to delete it, so a user cant delete other peoples messages,

then run a mysql code whish should look like this : `UPDATE`messages`SET`deleted`= '1' WHERE`id`= '16'`

i hope it helps you, let me know if you had any other questions.